# Can we query the TFS Database to find the Admins for all the agent queues in the agent pool

Tags: tfs

I have a requirement where we have to find the users who have "Administrator" role for all agent queues in our agent pool. I queried the TFS database and could fetch the list of existing agent queues and the users who created them. I have looked into TFS_Configuration and TFS_*MyCollection*.

I did explore the option of using the restAPI but its not available for the TFS version we have. As of now the only way I have is to manually get this information but I would really want to know if I can get this info in any other way.

Comment: You can use the `tfsrecurity.exe` tool to query security. You'll need to find the correct tokens to query the data though this buog explains the exploration process: https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-git-setting-default-repository-permissions/